# how to fetch files from removable SD card?

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage

This line of code:

```
ArrayList<File> mySongs = fetchSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

only fetches files from the internal storage of the device. and does not read the external removable SD card. I've also read that the "getExternalStorageDirectory" method is deprecated so is there an alternative? or is there any other method that fetches files from the external storage?
I have given external storage permission in the manifest as well.

Comment: Take the root of the second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs().

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! You can have an array of files from card and internal storage both with this piece of code:

```
String[] allPath = StorageUtil.getStorageDirectories(MainActivity.this);
                        File phoneStorage = new File(allPath[1]);
                        File sdCard = new File(allPath[0]);

ArrayList<File> phoneSongs = fetchSongs(phoneStorage);
                        ArrayList<File> sdCardSongs = fetchSongs(sdCard);

                        ArrayList<File> mySongs = new ArrayList<>();
                        mySongs.addAll(phoneSongs);
                        mySongs.addAll(sdCardSongs);
```

Note: You have to import StorageUtil class. search it on google.
I hope it helps someone! Good luck.